# Creating VirtualHost in httpd.conf file aws

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, httpd.conf

I have an PHP website up and running on AWS setup with elastic beanstalk. Its running httpd server and I am unable to figure out as how to create virtual host to run multiple sites. The httpd.conf file doesn't have VirtualHost tag and I am unable to figure out as how to create one. Please let me know as how to configure it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution is to create a `elasticbeanstalk.conf` file in the `.ebextensions` directory and you specify in it the changes you want to make in the apache config

Answer (score 0):

Actually the best solution is to include virtual host tags within the file and then defining the directory path in those tags.